# Run other JS from a Master JS Menu

Tags: javascript, node.js

Have a master menu from which other JS scripts will be executed when a user selects an option. Not exactly sure how I execute a JS from the master JS menu. I just want to exit the menu and run the JS out right. Do I still need to export the JS and somehow execute it?

```
runOptions();
var runOptions = function () {
    inquirer.prompt({
        name: "action",
        type: "list",
        message: "What do you want to do?",
        choices: [
            "Perform Magic",
            "Go To Bed",
            "Have a Vodka Martini"

        ]
    }).then(function (answer) {
        switch (answer.action) {
            case "Perform Magic":
                runMagicman();
                break;

            case "Go To Bed":
                runSleepyTime();
                break;

            case "Have a Vodka Martini":
                runGetDrunk();
                break;
        }
    });
}

var runMagicman = function () {
// Exit this menu and run magicman.js
}

var runSleepyTime = function () {
// Exit this menu and run sleepytime.js    
}

var runGetDrunk = function () {
// Exit this menu and run getdrunknow.js
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to export the runOptions function if the file that contains runOptions is the main entry point (Meaning you are doing node ./thisFile.js). As the main reason we want to export functions or classes is to group them by their feature or uses.

Also, a neat little trick for executing dynamic actions like this is to use .apply(), which will invoke the function with flexible parameters for each action.

```js
runOptions();
var runOptions = function () {
    inquirer.prompt({
        name: "action",
        type: "list",
        message: "What do you want to do?",
        choices: [
            "Perform Magic",
            "Go To Bed",
            "Have a Vodka Martini"

        ]
    }).then(function (answer) {
        const functionMapping = {"Perform Magic": runMagicman, "Go To Bed": runSleepyTime, "Have a Vodka Martini": runGetDrunk };
        const parameterMapping = {"Perform Magic": [answer.arg1], "Go To Bed": runSleepyTime: [answer.arg1, answer.arg2, answer.arg3], "Have a Vodka Martini": [answer.arg1, answer.arg2] };
        if (functionMapping[answer.action]){
          return functionMapping[answer.action].apply(null, parameterMapping[answer.action]);
        }
        throw "Action not found";
    });
}

var runMagicman = function (arg1) {
// Exit this menu and run magicman.js
}

var runSleepyTime = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
// Exit this menu and run sleepytime.js    
}

var runGetDrunk = function (arg1, arg2) {
// Exit this menu and run getdrunknow.js
}
```

Hope that help clear things up for you.

Comment: Perfect answer!